# Difficulty using ByteBuddyAgent, dynamic agent installation, and spaces in the classpath

Tags: java, byte-buddy, javaagents

I'm maintaining a white-box testing library that uses reflection to check the fields of objects for equality.  Our students are writing small programs, and for pedagogic reasons in the beginning of the course we avoid any issues of packages or modules.  After Java 9 introduced modules, obviously reflection across module boundaries became a lot harder, but tools like ByteBuddyAgent allow me to interpose on module loading, open all the modules, and regain reflective access.  My testing library currently works on Javas 8--12, on Windows and Linux.  On Mac, it works on Javas 8--11.  But in lab today, our students were running into issues with Java 12 on Macs.

My code uses `ByteBuddyAgent.install()` to install itself, so that students don't need to worry about fussy command line details.  On Macs, though, I'm running into [this exception](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-agent/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/agent/ByteBuddyAgent.java#L486), and I don't see anything in the JavaDoc for `install` that indicates why this should fail on Mac but not on other OSes.  I've confirmed that the students were installing the Oracle JDK 12 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html), and not just a JRE, so the caveats mentioned in the `ByteBuddyAgent#install` method shouldn't apply.

Is there something simple or silly that I'm missing, or some configuration that students need specifically on Mac, to make this work?

Comment: To add to the details, what version of byte-buddy were you using?

Comment: Using version 1.9.12

Comment: Don’t know why creating a process fails on MacOS, but `-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true` on the command line used to launch your testing software may eliminate the need to use a subprocess.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to engineer this so that my students don't need to know such magic incantations just to get their homeworks working.  They're running their programs directly in Eclipse, not the command line, and every bit of friction we can remove (in terms of Eclipse version-specific UI quirks to instruct, or details to remember for each homework they write) leads to major improvements in student success.

Comment: I do unfortunately not have a MacBook available to debug this and CI servers are rare in this space. Could you build Byte Buddy Agent yourself but write the exception trace at https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-agent/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/agent/Attacher.java#L78 to a file somewhere? I assume that the process is created but that something is wrong in its execution. There is also a chance that the process commands are incorrect; could you check the command line being executed at the place where you linked the exception in Byte Buddy Agent?

Comment: Apparently, this has nothing to do with Mac or with Java 12 :)  After debugging further with students, the only apparent difference in our setups was that the file path where my tester.jar file lived had no spaces in the path, whereas the students' paths had spaces.  It appears that `quote((selfResolvedJar == null ? attachmentJar : selfResolvedJar).getCanonicalPath())` isn't working to produce a properly quoted classpath.

I've edited the question title and tags to reflect this new understanding.